# regExp for methods and class names

Tags: php, regex, class, methods

I want to print all class names and methods for a PHP specific file. Here's the pattern:

```
public function methodName()
class className extends anotherClassName{
```

Desired output:

```
methodName
className
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you explain what "**public function methodName() **class className extends anotherClassName{" means?

Comment: What programming language is that anyway? PHP?

Comment: PHP sir. I just want to get the function name. I'm reading a php files and i want to print just the class and functions/method under the class. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)?